# change the input font language of text box on focus

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I have two text boxes to enter the name of the customer. In one text box I need to enter the name of the customer in English language and on another text box need to enter the name in hindi language. One way to do this is to change the computer language using `Alt Shift` key but it is tedious job for the user to change the font every time to move on to the text boxes.

Is there any way to change the font language using CSS and javascript as the user focuses on the text boxes.  So is there any way to change the font language and the user moves to the text boxes.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Name: </label><span class="required">*</span>
    <input type="text" required="required" class="form-control" maxlength="200" runat="server" id="txtEngName" autocomplete="off" />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>नाम: </label><span class="required">*</span>
    <input type="text" required="required" class="form-control" maxlength="200" runat="server" id="txtHindiName" autocomplete="off" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use lang attribute and font family attribute for particular element

```
#hindi{
font-family:your font;
lang: language;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
<input type="textbox" name="text1" Lang="HI-IR" />
```

You can view list lang

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp